# How do I add multiple data to one document in Android Firestore?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Data is stored only in list/0.
I want multiple data to be stored in the user's email.

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance(); 

final ArrayList<AddDayInfo> list = new ArrayList<>();
final Map<String,Object> docData = new HashMap<>();
AddDayInfo memberInfo = new AddDayInfo(Type,Day,Name,Time1,Time2,Time3);
list.add(memberInfo);

for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++) {
    if (user != null) {
        docData.put("Day_M", list);
        db.collection("day").document(user.getEmail()).set(docData, SetOptions.merge())
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                        startToast("Okay. Add Data..");
                        myStartActivity(Add_Main_Activity.class);
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        startToast("Failed...");
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

I want to add data like this picture:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add an item to an array in Firestore, you have two options:

- Use `FieldValue.arrayUnion` which ensures you have only unique elements in the array.
- Read the entire array, change it in your application code, and write it back.

The choice between these two depends on the meaning of your data, and I expect you'll actually need the second (more involved) option here.

---

We'll start with `FieldValue.arrayUnion`, just to show you how to do it:

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

if (user != null) {
    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance(); 
    DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("day").document(user.getEmail())

    AddDayInfo memberInfo = new AddDayInfo(Type,Day,Name,Time1,Time2,Time3);
    docRef.update("messages", FieldValue.arrayUnion(memberInfo))...
```

---

If you always want to add the message to the end of the array, even if another copy of the message is already in there, you'll need to:

1. Read the current contents of the array
2. Change the array in your application code
3. Write the full array back to the database

Since we're using the current value to determine the new value, it's best to use a transaction for this:

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

if (user != null) {
    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance(); 
    DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("day").document(user.getEmail())

    AddDayInfo memberInfo = new AddDayInfo(Type,Day,Name,Time1,Time2,Time3);

    db.runTransaction(new Transaction.Function<Void>() {
    @Override
    public Void apply(Transaction transaction) throws FirebaseFirestoreException {
        DocumentSnapshot snapshot = transaction.get(docRef);

        List messages = snapshot.get("messages");
        messages.add(memberInfo)

        transaction.update(docRef, "messages", messages);

        // Success
        return null;
    }
})
```